# JQuery .find and > (greater) selector withou parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) about the `>` selector, but it says `parent > child`.

But what it does when it's inside a `.find` and without a `parent` ?

e.g.

```
root.find("> div > span.k-in")
```

What does it means when it starts with `>` with no `parent` selector?

Comment: Then whatever element which is referred to in `root` becomes the parent to find within

Comment: The `>` is equivalent to `.children()` in jQuery

Comment: Thanks! That's all I need to know

Comment: `>` is the direct children selector, which means whatever comes after `> xyz` will only match within direct children

Comment: "*with no parent selector*" - `root.` is the parent